# global-set-key hotkeys not updating after reevaluating .ercrc.el file

Tags: erc

I am working on configuring ERC. As a starting point I'm copying portions of the [sample configuration file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/erc/Sample-Configuration.html). So my .ercrc.el file begins with something this (taken straight from that guide):

```
(global-set-key "\C-cef" (lambda () (interactive)
                           (erc :server "irc.freenode.net" :port "6667"
                                :nick "MYNICK")))
```

My problem is that if I change any of the parameters to erc inside the lambda, move to the end of the file, and I re-evaluate the file by pressing C-x C-e, the key still contains the old configuration values. The only way to make the change stick is to quit and open emacs again. How can I change what the C-c e f shortcut does without restarting emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> move to the end of the file, and I re-evaluate the file by pressing `C-x C-e`

That's not what <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> does.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> tells you:

```
C-x C-e runs the command eval-last-sexp
...
Evaluate sexp before point
```

That's the *single* expression before point; definitely not "the file".

You can evaluate the whole buffer with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer`.